# How can I read the 1st cluster of Volume C of Windows PC by using win32file.BackupRead in Python?

Tags: python, windows, createfile, computer-forensics

**What I want to do**

I want to directly access and read Volume C of Windows PC and write it as a binary file.

**Issues**

- My script doesn't give any error, but doesn't work as I expect.
- The size of the output file, T:\001.bin, stays 0 even after the process.
- "print(data_buf)" doesn't show anything

**My script**

```
# I want to read the first 4096 bytes of Windows's C drive and write it to "T:\001.bin" by this script. But can't,,,,

import win32file
import win32con
import ctypes
  
target = r"\\.\C:"
output = r"T:\001.bin"

handle = win32file.CreateFile(
    target,
    win32con.GENERIC_READ,
    win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    None,
    win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
    win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
    None
    )

out_handle = win32file.CreateFile(
    output,
    win32con.GENERIC_READ | win32con.GENERIC_WRITE,
    win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    None,
    win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
    win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    None
    )

bytestoread = 4096
buf = bytearray(b" " * 4096)
ctxt = ctypes.pointer(ctypes.c_int(5))
pntr = ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer(ctxt).value

bytes_read, data_buf, pointer = win32file.BackupRead(
                    handle,
                    bytestoread,
                    buf,
                    False,
                    True,
                    pntr
                    )

print(data_buf) # This shows nothing, somehow.               

win32file.WriteFile(out_handle, data_buf)

win32file.BackupRead(handle, 0, buf, True, True, pntr)
win32file.CloseHandle(handle)
win32file.CloseHandle(out_handle)
```

**Documents I have read**

I have been trying to find the solution by modifing the prameters of win32file.BackupRead but I still don't know it. These are the documents I have read so far.

- http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32file__BackupRead_meth.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-backupread

**My Wish**

Can anyone show me how to use "BackupRead" correctly in python scripts ?  If so, that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running the python script in an elevated command line/powershell?

Comment: Yes, I'm running the script in "Windows Powershell (Admin)"

Comment: Has anyone successfully used "win32file.BackupRead" in Python ?

Comment: I found this forum post, he does something with access rights: https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/backupread-problem.742093/
Maybe this helps?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However the script there has "ctx = 0" and this at least should give an error. Moreover, the question there has no answer for more than a decade. Therefore , as far as I uderstand, that is not a good working script. But thanks anyway for your message. I really appreciate it.